# AdMob Cancellation Threshold

Tags: admob, adsense

What is the threshold to get paid after closing an AdMob account?

On [AdMob help](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2772208) it says:

> The table below lists the different thresholds for each reporting currency.

but there is no table below.

Then I found [this overview](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1709871#c), but it is for AdSense. Can I assume the threshold is the same for AdMob?

**Edit: I didn't see the table using Firefox or Chrome, but Microsoft Edge displayed it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cancellation threshold**

If you decide to cancel your account and your account balance is greater than the cancellation threshold, you'll receive your final payment within approximately 90 days of the end of the month, provided that you've completed the necessary steps to get paid.

The table below lists the different thresholds for each [reporting currency](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2789022).

[image: Payment thresholds]

**How to find your reporting currency**

Complete the following steps to find the reporting currency of your account.

1. Sign in to your AdMob account at https://apps.admob.com.
2. Go to the Monetize > Performance reports page.
3. Check what currency your earnings are displayed in. This is the
   reporting currency of your account.

Comment: Thanks..using a third browser I can also see it.